# macro pulling data from different file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a daily dashboard file in which I'm pulling data on a daily basis from 5 different files with a macro. The macro works fine but it is asking which file I should choose for specific steps: `Workbooks.Open vFile` (a window appears and I just select the file). Those files are being changed on a weekly or monthly basis so what I want to do is to insert the source in a specific cell and the macro won't ask me for the file but will take the source there.

Is this possible?

Code (I'm not putting the entire code but just the part I want to change)

```
vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (.xl)," & ".xl", 1, "select WF Report", "Open", False) 

Workbooks.Open vFile
```

And then the macro is refering to the active file & sheet. Once I have all the data copied, another window prompts and I select the 2nd file etc.

```
vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (.xl)," & ".xl", 1, "select Front End Tracker ", "Open", False)

Workbooks.Open vFile
```

What I want to change is that, instead of having the window for file selection, I want the macro to take the source and name of the file from a specific cell in the Excel sheet. Any ideas on how to do so?

Comment: obviously it's possible... but your question is a bit unclear. And it's rather necessary to show the code you have and point the part you want to change...

Comment: @KazJaw Sorry, the whole macro is very long so I think the part for opening the file is enough:  vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xl*)," & "*.xl*", 1, "select WF Report", "Open", False)  Workbooks.Open vFile<br/>And then the macro is refering to the active file & sheet. Once I have all the data copied, another window prompts and I select the 2 nd file etc.  vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xl*)," & "*.xl*", 1, "select Front End Tracker ", "Open", False)  Workbooks.Open vFile

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with all this editing.

Comment: try again please, try to edit your question instead of putting code into comment...

Comment: [**`various ways to pull data out of open and closed workbooks`**](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/various-ways-to-pull-data-out-of-a-closed-or-opened-workbook-using-excel-formulas-and-vba/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is quite easy but I'll try to provide you some options.

A) if you put in cell A1 complete path name and file name, like:

```
c:\users\user_name\Documents\files\moj plik.xlsx
```

then you only need to change your code as follows:

```
'comment this line by adding ' at the beginning
'vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (.xl)," & ".xl", 1, "select WF Report", "Open", False) 
'change next line by adding reference to the cell
Workbooks.Open Range("A1")
'or with reference to sheet name and range A1- change according to your situation
Workbooks.Open Sheets("put here sheet name").Range("A1")
```

B) if you want to refer to file names only you need to define in some way path to the file. If your cell A1 has only file name like:

```
moj plik.xlsx
```

then your code will be changed accordingly:

```
'comment this line by adding ' at the beginning
'vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (.xl)," & ".xl", 1, "select WF Report", "Open", False) 
'change by adding reference to the cell and path constant
Dim xlsPath as String
    xlsPath = "c:\users\user_name\Documents\files\"
'change above accordingly to what you have
Workbooks.Open xlsPath & Range("A1")
'or with reference to sheet name and range A1- change according to your situation
Workbooks.Open xlsPath & Sheets("put here sheet name").Range("A1")
```

Comment: It was indeed quite easy. Thank you so much!